# Replacing a string with a random number using awk

Tags: variables, random, awk, gsub

I am currently trying to create an script that will start a vpn server on a new IP range. I have multiple servers, so there is a possibility of conflict if the 2 servers are using the same range.

I would therefore like to randomise the IP range that the server is started on. I would ideally like to randomise the IP in the following way in the generated config file;

```
    ifconfig 10.xxx.yyy.1 255.255.255.248
    server 10.xxx.yyy.0 255.255.255.248
```

The shell I am using is quite restricted, so many utilities like od are not available to create random numbers. However awk is available, so I think this will be suitable. I have had a stab at creating a command which will replace xxx and yyy with a random number between 0 and 255 but I haven't succeeded. Can anyone help me with this?

```
    awk '{var = int(rand() * 256); var2 = int(rand() * 256);  gsub(/xxx/, var ); gsub(/yyy/, var2 ) ; print}' /tmp/vpn.conf
```

This command changes the values to

```
    ifconfig 10.125.248.1 255.255.255.248
    server 10.74.196.0 255.255.255.248
```

which is obviously not desirable as both of xxx and yyy should be the same, eg

```
    ifconfig 10.25.64.1 255.255.255.248
    server 10.25.64.0 255.255.255.248
```

Can anyone assist in having awk perform the intended function? Alternatively, any simplified random number scripts will also suffice, however I am not hopeful of this working due to the lack of shell utilities available.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Generate the random numbers in the `BEGIN` block.

```
awk 'BEGIN{var = int(rand() * 256); var2 = int(rand() * 256)}  {sub(/xxx/, var ); sub(/yyy/, var2 ) ; print}' /tmp/vpn.conf
```

Also, there's no reason to use `gsub`, just use `sub` since there's only one replacement per line of the particular pattern.